# Python argparser not recognised

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python script that takes one argument from the user.
I want to throw a message if the input is not part of the list of possible inputs.
However, I get the "Unknown direction..." message despite the right input being provided. What is the issue? Why the values are not being compared to the `known_directions` list?

```
import argparse

known_directions = ['start', 'stop', 'left', 'right', 'forward', 'back']

class Direction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        direction = values
        if direction.lower() not in known_directions:
            parser.error("Unknown direction. Available direction are 'start', 'stop', 'left', 'right', 'forward', & 'back'")
        namespace.direction = direction.lower()


def create_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="""
    Control the movement of your bot.
    """)
    parser.add_argument('--direction', '-d',
                        help='which direction to move',
                        nargs=1,
                        metavar=("DIRECTION"),
                        action=Direction,
                        required=True)
    return parser

parser = create_parser()
parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: When I run this code, I get an error on `if direction.lower() not in known_directions:` because `direction` is a list.  I don't see how this code runs at all for you.

Comment: I don't know why I am not getting the error, however I think as the comment below mentions 'nargs=1' produces list. So only the first element needs to be retrieved (i.e. 'direction = values[0]').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the python docs - https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs

> Note that nargs=1 produces a list of one item. This is different from
>   the default, in which the item is produced by itself.

You'll need to make `direction = values[0]`

Also, you might want to look at the choices keyword argument to do that.

```
import argparse

known_directions = ['start', 'stop', 'left', 'right', 'forward', 'back']
def create_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="""
    Control the movement of your bot.
    """)
    parser.add_argument('--direction', '-d',
                        help='which direction to move',
                        choices = known_directions, ## <---- new
                        required=True)
    return parser

parser = create_parser()
parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `choices` kwarg in `add_argument` to do this for you.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#choices